# Oracle - using is not null inside Case when.... then.... inside Where

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i am here to ask again 
i being confused with Oracle , its seems that when i use is null inside a case when function , it wont work , my code is like this :
it went wrong around the 
`"CASE WHEN :idSalesman is not null then enabled = null and deleted=0 else enabled =1 and deleted =0"` condition

```
SELECT a.id_outlet as idOutlet , a.name , a.plant as plant, a.segment, a.street1 as alamat, a.nota_retur  
 FROM (SELECT id_outlet, name, plant, segment, street1, nota_retur FROM outlet WHERE plant = :idPlant  
 AND (id_outlet || ' ' || name || ' ' || street1) like :request  
 AND enabled = 1 AND deleted = 0 and rownum = :limits ) a  
 INNER JOIN wilayah_kerja b ON b.id_salesman = nvl(:idSalesman, b.id_salesman) AND  b.id_outlet = a.id_outlet 
 AND b.enabled = 1 AND b.deleted = 0  
 GROUP BY a.id_outlet  
 UNION  
 SELECT
    A.Id_Outlet AS Idoutlet,A.Name,A.Plant AS Plant,A.Segment,A.Street1 AS Alamat,A.Nota_Retur
FROM ( SELECT Id_Outlet,Name,Plant,Segment,Street1,Nota_Retur 
        FROM Outlet
    WHERE Plant =:Idplant 
    AND (CASE WHEN :idSalesman is not null then enabled = null and deleted=0 else enabled =1 and deleted =0 )
    AND rownum >=:limits 
    AND (Id_Outlet || ' ' || Name || ' ' || Street1) LIKE :Request
    )a
 LEFT JOIN wilayah_kerja b ON b.id_outlet = a.id_outlet 
 and rownum = :limits
 AND b.enabled = 1 
 AND b.deleted = 0  
 WHERE B.Id_Outlet Is NULL Group By A.Id_Outlet Order By Name Limit 10;
```

i tried to change the union to :

```
 SELECT a.id_outlet as idOutlet , a.name , a.plant as plant, a.segment, a.street1 as alamat, a.nota_retur  
 FROM (SELECT id_outlet, name, plant, segment, street1, nota_retur FROM outlet WHERE plant = :idPlant  
 AND (id_outlet || ' ' ||  name || ' ' || street1 ) like :request  
 AND rownum = :limits
 AND enabled = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND NVL(:idSalesman , enabled = null AND deleted = 0))a  
 LEFT JOIN wilayah_kerja b ON b.id_outlet = a.id_outlet AND b.enabled = 1 AND b.deleted = 0  
 WHERE B.Id_Outlet Is NULL Group By A.Id_Outlet Order By Name Limit 10
```

using NVL2 , but it give me error near "a"

```
NVL(:idSalesman , enabled = null AND deleted = 0))a
```

Comment: Let's simplify. What do you think `case when :param is not null then id = 300` means? (That is: what did you want it to mean?) It is 100% wrong in SQL. The `THEN` part of a `CASE` expression must be an **expression** (something that returns a value) - not a Boolean condition. So - what did you try to achieve with that code? Your attempt to fix it using `NVL` (or `NVL2`, it's not clear) suffers from exactly the same problem; it fails for the same reason.

Comment: CMIIW , but then i put {case when :idSalesman is null } i want the expresion to assign null on enabled column and 0 on deleted column , i think the expresion is not wrong

Comment: If you want to conditionally assign values to two different columns, you must use a different `CASE` expression for each (even if the `WHEN` part is the same). The `CASE` expression is, well, an expression, it is not a statement. (`CASE` statements do exist - in PL/SQL, not in SQL). You can't "assign" to two different columns at the same time in SQL. And assignments wouldn't be done in a `WHERE` clause, anyway.

Comment: Is this means i need to move the query to procedure?

Comment: change that case to CASE 
 WHEN :idSalesman is not null and enabled is null and deleted=0 then 1 
 WHEN :idSalesman is null and enabled =1 and deleted =0 then 1
 else 0 
end = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support a separate boolean type in SQL statements.  One problem (at least) is:

```
WHERE Plant = :Idplant AND
      (CASE WHEN :idSalesman is not null then enabled = null and deleted = 0 else enabled = 1 and deleted = 0 ) AND
      rownum >= :limits AND
      . . .
```

The solution is just to phrase this as boolean logic:

```
WHERE Plant = :Idplant AND
      deleted = 0 AND
      (:idSalesman is not null and enabled is null OR 
       :idSalesman is null and enabled = 1
      ) AND
      rownum >= :limits AND
      . . .
```

Also note that `= null` is not a valid comparison (unless you never want something to evaluate to true).